# How to use ajax.reload or fnReloadAjax in Data Tables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

manage_course_subject.php code table

```
<table id="manage_course_subject" class="display table table-hover ">
    <thead>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click `onclick="return add_course_subject_form();"`

In file script.js use this function

```
var table = $('#manage_course_subject').dataTable();
function add_course_subject_form(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process.php",
        data:$("#add_course_subject_form").serialize(),
        success:function(data){     
            //close modal
            $(".close").trigger("click");           
            //show result
            alert(data);            
            //reload page
            // location.reload();
            // manage_course_subject.api().ajax.reload();
            // table.fnReloadAjax();
            // table.api().ajax.reload();
            // table.ajax.reload();
            // table.api().ajax.reload();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

When I use fnReloadAjax() I include

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'media/js/fnReloadAjax.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

I try but didn't work the 2nd way 
Can anyone help me?